# jquery live don't work and the code is simple

Tags: jquery, html

hello i just programmed a simple code because i'm learning jquery this is the code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('input[type="file"]').live({
    change : function(){
      alert('ok');
    }
  });
});
```

but it doesn't want to work what is the problem?

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using? `.live()` was deprecated in 1.7.

Comment: Not to mention totally removed in 1.9.

Comment: Note, if your binding to the document, you don't need `$(document).ready(`

Answer (score 1):

live is deprecated try this:

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/urT4G/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $(document).on('change','input[type="file"]',function(){
         alert('ok');
     });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The jQuery `live()` [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/live/) states :

> As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. Use .on() to
>   attach event handlers. Users of older versions of jQuery should use
>   .delegate() in preference to .live().

Use `on()` ([documentation](http://api.jquery.com/on/)) to bind your event (if the element was not added dynamically) :

```
$('input[type="file"]').on('change',function (){
   //Stuff
});
```

*Note : this does exactly the same thing as `$('input[type="file"]').change()`*

If you used `live()` to bind functions to **dynamically added DOM elements**, you should use `on()` like this :

```
$(document).on('change', 'input[type="file"]', function (){
   //Stuff
});
```

Comment: this is what i mean http://jsfiddle.net/7Ny57/1/ every time i click on the button it will apear alert with ok and duplicate the buootn again when i press it it will still do the same work

Comment: @user2174729 You didn't include jQuery on your fiddle. **Did you include jQuery on your webpage?** Please read again my answer, especially the part on **dynamically added** elements, and check that [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bigood/9xjQW/1/) as a correction of yours

Answer (score 0):

`.live()` has been removed since jQuery 1.9

Try using `$('input[type="file"]').change(function() { ... })` instead

Comment: So you might propose an alternative, he?

Comment: done, don't get mad :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use .on().live() is deprecated.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $(document).on('change','input[type="file"]',function(){
     alert('ok');
 });
});
```

Comment: thx i didn't it but it doesn't do the same work as live look to my seconde code   $(document).ready(function(){
  $('.duplicated').on("click",function(){
      alert('ok');
      $(this).after('<input class="duplicated" type="submit" value="click">');
  });
});

Comment: @user2174729 i updated my code.check it once